# How to match list elements to indexes in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame from Pandas:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index_list=[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
names_list=['Bob','Mike','Tom']

df=pd.DataFrame(vals_index,columns=['names'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    names
0       0
1       0
2       0
3       1
4       1
5       1
6       1
7       1
8       1
9       2
10      2
```

Now I want to match the names_list to the column names in this example:

- 0 --> Bob
- 1 --> Mike
- 2 --> Tom

I am want output like this:

```
0       Bob
1       Bob
2       Bob
3       Mike
4       Mike
5       Mike
6       Mike
7       Mike
8       Mike
9       Tom
10      Tom
```

Comment: Take a look at [**`pd.Series.map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :

---

```
df.names.map({0: 'Bob', 1: 'Mike', 2: 'Tom'})
```